Book in which a girl finds out she’s a fairy and sees a future where her mother is in a car crash
I’m looking for a book I read back in 2011-2012.
I remember it was a girl that discovered she was a fairy. She had a companion travel dimensions with her. The biggest detail I remember is that she could see the future and saw her mom in a car crash, so she had to stop it.

Is there actual time travel in this book? You added the [time-travel] tag but only mentioned precognition in your description of the plot.

I wonder if you might be remembering part of Michael Swanwick's novel The Iron Dragon's Daughter?
